# Facebook: aggregate action in news feed, show description instead of caption

Tags: facebook, object, action, facebook-opengraph

Hi，i have a customized action with caption defined in attachment. If i trigger the action once a time, the post on news feed will show that caption i defined. However, if i trigger the action many time, the post on news feed will show og:description on meta tag instead of the caption line. 
Since description is for each public page, and my caption is related to action (e.g Run XX miles), i'd like the post always show caption. 
Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. And it's not related to aggregation, as the proposed answer below suggests. The action story is missing all its captions in the feed, even though it appears correctly in timeline. In the feed, just the og:image and og:title appear. What happened to the captions?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which type of data an aggregation should show as caption – and use data extracted from your action/object in that caption, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/#captions:

> **Caption Lines**
>
> Aggregations support a simple text template syntax for formatting Open Graph action / object properties into strings that a user sees.

Also follow the link to [Using Text Templates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/template) given there – it explains it in more detail.

Comment: hi CBroe, that's exactly what i'm doing now. But the aggregation captions only apply in user's own Timeline, not news feed. In news feed, aggregated post only show og:description on meta tag instead of the caption line